# A relation that is both an equivalence relation and a function.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

The question is: "Suppose R on A is both an equivalence relation on A and a function from A to A. What is R?" I'm not entirely sure where to start, I'm not even sure I understand what a function from A to A represents, can anybody help with this?

Comment: A relation on $A$ is a set of points in $A\times A$ (and an equivalence relation is such a set with some additional properties).  A function is also such a set of points (but each $a\in A$ must appear as the first coordinate in exactly one element of this set).  So, Hint:  think about the additional properties an equivalence relation must have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the following definitions for a relation $R$ on a set $A$ (hence $R \subseteq A \times A$). These are adjectives which describe the kind of relation $R$ is.

- **Reflexive:** For each $a \in A$, $(a,a) \in R$
- **Symmetric:** Whenever $(a,b) \in R$, then $(b,a) \in R$
- **Transitive:** Whenever $(a,b),(b,c) \in R$, then $(a,c) \in R$
- **Functional/Right-Unique:** If $(x,y),(x,z) \in R$, then $y=z$

  - In other words, if $a$ is related to any other two elementsin $A$, then those must be the *same* element.
  - Or put differently, any $a$ must be related to either zero or one elements.
  - A totality axiom (i.e. that each $a \in A$ is related to one thing) may be required to match the "typical" definition of a function, as usually given.
- **Equivalence:** Reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity all apply

So, consider a relation $R$ which is a right-unique equivalence relation.

- From reflexivity, we know $\{ (a,a) \mid a \in A \} \subseteq R$
- From right-uniqueness, any $a \in A$ can only be related to one element. That is, $a$ can be in the left-coordinate of at most one pair in the relation.

In fact, you don't even need symmetry or transitivity to see what results.

Comment: Am I wrong in saying that that explanation sounds like f(x)=x?

Comment: Nope, that is precisely what you need to observe -- that the function described is the identity function on $A$.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, thank you for the help. Just for clarification, would simply saying the relation is the identity function be sufficient or would I need to find a relation that satisfies that criteria?

Comment: I think that would be a perfectly fine answer myself